# How do we know which qirat were abrogated and which we can continue to recite?

Tags: quran, qiraat

In this video at 15.30 he explains that a possible explanation for sahaba reciting certain variations of the Qur'an could be that those variants were then abrogated after the final review of the Qur'an (during Ramadan, Jibreel and the Prophet pbuh) https://youtu.be/GCU_2WX_sBA

This is just one explanation and another is that they were only explaining the verse.

But if it was an abrogation, then How would we know if we are reciting abrogated qirat or qirat that are still valid, as I thought Uthman wrote it in the dialect of Quraish, so why do we recite with different dialects? What if those dialects are abrogated?

Or do the minor differences between Uthmani manuscripts mean he still acknowledged that different dialects were allowed?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For further information about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. Please check posts with the tag [tag:qiraat] and then ask if you feel your question has not been addressed. I personally think it has been explained on the site.

Comment: Wa alaikum assalam I did try to read through those and I still don't understand. Sorry, are there any links to anything where I can understand the history of qirat from the beginning? I don't understand how people knew which Qirat they were allowed to continue and which were abrogated. Is it because Uthman sent reciters to go with the manuscripts to different places?

Comment: yes after the Moshaf al-Imam was written. 'Othman sent out reciters with copies. The qur'an ever since was transmitted orally. Anything that has no backup in the script, the language and is not sahih (mutawatir according some scholars) is no longer valid.

Comment: With regards to them being mutawattir- Some people argue that it's ahad not mutawattir. And I've heard of people saying there's a consensus on them being mutawattir but then there are scholars apparently such as as-shawkaani who say they are ahad. Why is there not a consensus on such a big matter like this?

Comment: For answering this one needs to read to full statement and the relevant circumstances. By now it is very likely that they are ahaad. Because most of the people who live now are trying to read the 7 or 10 qira'at according the given books. As qira'at certainly is a specification almost all layman don't know more than one riwaya. But I don't know if this is the reason why he said so. I'm also uncertain if it was a-Shawkani (I rather doubt it was him) or somebody else. At least I've read this in a book about 'Ulum al-Qur'an.

Comment: This topic really confuses me, maybe there's a good book on it

Answer (score -1):

The Qiraa'at are authentic dialects of the Quran and the Rasool (saw) himself said they were revealed to him by Jibreel. Whichever of the seven dialects you recite is accurate and it is no abrogation. The hadith of Bukhari says

> “The Qur’an was revealed in 7 Ahruf” (Bukhari)

Therefore, it is no abrogation. Abrogation (Naskh) is when a hukm in a verse or hadith replaced with another verse or hadith.

The Qur’an was revealed in 7 different dialects as mentioned by the Prophet (saw) himself, and the various Qira’aat are simply different mixes of these 7 dialects which most Muslims around the world recite today. Read detailed explanation with evidences [here](https://www.islamiqate.com/3983/what-are-the-7-ahruf-dialects-of-the-quran)

Comment: Qirats are NOT Ahrufs. There is a difference between these two things. Your answer is incorrect.

Comment: This might be a stupid question but on the website it says that Qirat are a mix of certain ahruf. How were they able to tell that these qirat were not the original ahruf (when they first noted the original 7)? If that made sense.

Comment: @user39559 This is not a stupid question, but a question that is very interesting and requires much research.